# No tick labels and adding title to groupplot generated plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am generating an array of plots using `pgfplots` and more specifically the `groupplot` environment. Here is an example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,horizontal sep=0.2cm,vertical sep=0.2cm},height=3cm,width=3cm] 
\nextgroupplot \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
\nextgroupplot \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)}; 
\nextgroupplot \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\nextgroupplot \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to be able to eliminate either the x or the y tick labels or both. I also want to add a different title to each plot. I have not found a way to do this in the documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

For the tick labels, you have the `xticklabels at` and `xticklabels at` keys for `group style`.

For the titles, you can pass the `title=<text>` option to `\nextgroupplot`.

A little complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
  group size=2 by 2,
  horizontal sep=0.2cm,
  vertical sep=0.8cm,
  xticklabels at=edge bottom,
  yticklabels at=edge right
  },
height=3cm,
width=3cm,
] 
\nextgroupplot[title=Plot A]
  \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
\nextgroupplot[title=Plot B]
  \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)}; 
\nextgroupplot[title=Plot C]
  \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\nextgroupplot[title=Plot D]
  \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I want to get rid of the labels in every plot, I see I can use the command `\nextgroupplot[title=Plot 11,xticklabels={,,},yticklabels={,,}] \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};`. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid adding `xticklabels={,,},yticklabels={,,}` to every plot. I tried moving that to the `group style` but that did not work.