# Adding title to plots in groupplot from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfplotstable, groupplots

I am plotting a lower triangular matrix of plots with `groupplot`, and I would like to add a title to the plots on the diagonal. I generate these plots by reading data using `\foreach`, and therefore need to access the title strings via either a file or a list stored in pgfplots.

The title file would have a math environment in them, like the code below. Is there a way to apply these values to the plot below? For this example the three diagonal plots would have the titles `{$\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $beta$}`.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\newcounter{irun}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{plot_titles.txt}
$\alpha_1$
$\alpha_2$
$\beta$
$\gamma$
$\delta$
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 3},
    view={0}{90},
    try min ticks=2,
    max space between ticks=50,
    width=3.5cm,
    height=3.5cm]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in { % the following table is generated by a script
    1 / 1,
    1 / 2,
    1 / 3,
    2 / 1,
    2 / 2,
    2 / 3,
    3 / 1,
    3 / 2,
    3 / 3}{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\b{int(\theirun - 1)}
          \ifnum\i=\j
            \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot\noexpand\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};} % Line plot
            \temp
            \typeout{\i=\j}
          \else
            \ifnum\j>\i
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]} % No plot
                \temp
                \typeout{\j>\i}
            \else
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot\noexpand\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};} % Contour plot
                \temp
                \typeout{\j<\i}
            \fi
          \fi
    }
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Generated output from MWE]

Comment: You have seen this link? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129313/no-tick-labels-and-adding-title-to-groupplot-generated-plots?rq=1. Your question is similar to the question of the link.

Comment: @marmot I did not absolutely vote for the closure of the user's question. It seemed similar to the charts I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{plot_titles.txt}
$\alpha_1$
$\alpha_2$
$\beta$
$\gamma$
$\delta$
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
% read the table
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{plot_titles.txt}{\mytable}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 3},
    view={0}{90},
    try min ticks=2,
    max space between ticks=50,
    width=3.5cm,
    height=3.5cm]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in { % the following table is generated by a script
    1 / 1,
    1 / 2,
    1 / 3,
    2 / 1,
    2 / 2,
    2 / 3,
    3 / 1,
    3 / 2,
    3 / 3}{\pgfmathtruncatemacro\b{int(\i - 1)}
          \ifnum\i=\j
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\b}{0}\of\mytable
            \edef\Name{\pgfplotsretval}
            \edef\temp{
            \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title={\Name}]\noexpand\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};} % Line plot
            \temp
            \typeout{\i=\j}
          \else
            \ifnum\j>\i
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]} % No plot
                \temp
                \typeout{\j>\i}
            \else
                \edef\temp{\noexpand\nextgroupplot\noexpand\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};} % Contour plot
                \temp
                \typeout{\j<\i}
            \fi
          \fi
    }
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The irun counter was not needed. Where did you get that from? ;-)

Comment: Thanks again! Oddly enough, you can't seem to use `\mathrm{}` in the titles, as it throws an error. For the time being I'll just use `\text{}`, but may look into why in the future if it bugs me.

Comment: @chasely I confirm your observation, and was not able to cure this with a reasonable amount of `\noexpand`s. Nor am I able to fix the lualatex issue. These might really important questions for real experts like Christian Feuersänger or Torbjørn T..